# ACCESS Query does not find all records

Tags: query, microsoft-access-2013

I am testing a simple database of patient recorded vitals. I am trying to do a query of those patients with a BGL >250 within the last week. I have put in test data to trigger return but not all records are returning. I put in same data for 2 different patients. It works beautifully finding BGL values >250 or dates out of range but only returns for records for 1 patient. There is no criteria set for any other fields.

Record data, query and the records returned:
[image: See record data, query and the records returned attached here]

Answer (score 1):

I found that because I was linked to a third table, there must be data in one of the fields of that table or it would not return any information from that patient. I deleted that linked table for this query as it was not needed. Problem solved, all records are returning now.